# When downloading an emulator for SDK 31 via Device Manger, why does a HAXM not Required Message appear after completing the installation as follows?

Tags: android, device

When downloading an emulator for SDK 31 via Device Manger, why does a HAXM not Required Message appear after completing the installation as follows ..?

[Emulater Running Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jM6tz.png)

Emulation Performance is not enough ... After checking the Emulator Settings, I also looked at the **intel * HAXM Documentation**. But it was difficult to slow down.

Invoking installer finish comes with Windows Command Processor.

Answer (score 0):

Search Control Panel--->Uninstall a program(programs section)--->Click the **Turn Windows features on or off**---> select the **Hyper-V** -->ok and restart